# How to disable R warning: timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone ()

Tags: r, timezone, warnings

I keep getting this warning: `timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone ().` My current timezone is "EET", as shown by `Sys.timezone()`.

Is there a way to change the R timezone to UTC, instead of it taking the one from my system? Or to disable the warning?

Comment: FYI just filled [xts#109](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/109).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is provision for getting a local timezone it is from:

```
 Sys.timezone()
[1] ""  # So in my case nothing there
```

And there is no Sys.timezone()<- function

```
 Sys.time()
[1] "2011-01-06 16:01:10 EST"
```

But obviously something is to be had. And here is how to convert to another time zone:

```
 strftime(Sys.time() , tz="UTC")
[1] "2011-01-06 21:02:48"
```

For further specific advice perhaps if you offered the results of dput() on the object, we would all have access to any necessary attributes to answer further questions.

Comment: Thanks for dput, I wanted something like this, and wasn't aware of it. My data is already in UTC (by calling with tz="UTC" the functions which built it). The problem was that my display timezone was not UTC.

Comment: Great. Also great that Gabor had the answer. His R skills are not accurately reflected in the current points system. Bumped his answer-arrow.

Comment: How do you check the "display timezone"?

Comment: Ah, I guess there is a difference btw. Sys.timezone() and Sys.getenv("TZ"). Former is the system and latter is the R-environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your code works and other sources of warnings are not likely, then just put the call inside suppressWarnings().

For example,

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("FDX")
suppressWarnings(chartSeries(FDX,theme="white"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work with xts data type (let's call the xts object xts.ts) from the package xts you can use:

`tzone(xts.ts) <- "America/Phoenix"`

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this page, as I kept getting this exact same warning too when trying to import manager return data from an excel spreadsheet into a `data.frame` and then converting the `data.frame` to an `xts`. Even `xts(x = my.data, order.by = my.dates, tz = Sys.timezone())` did not solve it for me, despite my system and the `xts` having obviously the same time zone!

How did I solve this without tempering with the system?
Very simple.
Instead of constructing my `xts` with the construct `xts(x = my.data, order.by = my.dates)` where `my.dates` look like: `2014-01-31`, `2014-02-28`, etc... which kept producing the annoying warning, I simply used `xts(x = my.data, order.by = as.Date(my.dates))`
Solved: no more warning.